# Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, string, datatable, datarow

I have a datable code to generate a string, which is sb.ToString().

```
DataTable dt = dbaccess.GetDataTable("TEST"); // get datatable
List<DataRow> drlist = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList(); // each row only has one element.
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
foreach (DataRow row in drlist)
{
    foreach (string str in row.ItemArray)
    {
        sb.Append(str);
    }
}
```

The datatable is

```
NULL
0
138
337
1666
1680
2511
8113
```

You see that there is "NULL" to cause the error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'. 
How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (object str in row.ItemArray) 
{ 
    if (DbNull.Value.Equals(str))
       sb.Append("NULL");
    else
       sb.Append(str.ToString()); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your loop:

```
foreach(var obj in row.ItemArray)
{
    if(obj is string) sb.Append(obj as string);
}
```

Comment: But it sounds like `obj` might be `DbNull`, not `null`, no?

Answer (score 1):

```
            if(!row.IsNull("column"))
            {
                foreach (string str in row.ItemArray)
                {
                    sb.Append(str);
                }                
            }
```